# Unable to check and compare timestamp time

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hi I'm trying to check a timestamp on a member that has joined the Discord server. I want to check to see if the member has joined within 14 days before removing the role called newbie.

Here I'm trying to compare the `member.joinedTimestamp` to the amount of days after they have joined in this case 14 days. After testing the code it always returns false despite the user having been joined longer than 14 days.

Here is what I'm working with.

Help would be appreciated.

```
        const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(ID);
        const Role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Newbies"); // The role to remove if the member has been in the server for 14 or more days
        Role.members.forEach((member) => { // Looping through the members of Role.
            const TwoWeeks = 1209600000; // Use to compare timestamp with two weeks.
            if (member.joinedTimestamp > TwoWeeks){  // If returns a false because joinedTimestamp is not greater than two week return it
                return console.log("This is false")
            } else {
                member.roles.remove(Role); // Else If returns true then remove the role.
                return console.log("This is true")
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I saw the timestamp you are comparing is static and not the current timestmap, you will have to subtract the current timestamp with the timestamp from the user's entry date on the server, if the subtraction result is less than 1209600 ( 14 days ) return false, otherwise true.
Something like:

```js
function checkTimestamp(enterTimestamp) {
     if((new Date().getTime() - enterTimestamp) >= 1209600) {
         return true; // more than 14 days
     }else{
         return false; // less than 14 days
     }
}
```

Comment: `member.joinedTimestamp` is the timestamp and this returns when the user joined the server and I'm wanting to compare `member.joinedTimestamp`` to 14 days.` :) Not sure what you mean by current timestamp

Comment: @troxie i've edited with real resolution, I hope you can do verification now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm intrigued to know why is it that you would take/negate `- enterTimestamp` away from `new Date().getTime()` ?

Comment: @troxie Sorry, I'm horrible to explain. What we have to do and see if the time difference between the date the user enters the server until today is 14 days, 14 days in seconds are 1209600 seconds, what I do is get the timestamp which is the date counted in seconds from Jan 01 1970 and subtract by the date in timestamp of today, and see if the difference between the two gives the amount of seconds equivalent to 14 days, if more it means that it has been on the server for more than 14 days , in case it is not less than 14 days since he entered.

Comment: @troxie we can say that the result of subtracting (new Date().getTime() - enterTimestamp) is the time in seconds that the user remained on the server.